# controller $scope variables undefined in jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing my first Angular app tests with Karma and Jasmine.

I have a controller with this function:

```
function getMyLists() {
  getLists.getOne().then(function(listOne) {
    $scope.list1 = listOne[0];
    list1Available = true;
  });
  getLists.getTwo().then(function(listTwo) {
    $scope.list2 = listTwo;
    list2Available = true;
  });
}

getMyLists();
```

I have Mocked out the service in the test

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {

  var rootScope, scope, controller, myService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    myService = {
      getOne: function(){
        // mock promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([
          {
            "one": 1
         },
         {
            "type": list
         }
        ]);
        return deferred.promise;
      },
      getTwo: function(){
        // mock promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve([
          {
            "two": 2
         },
         {
            "type": list
         }
        ]);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }

    controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      myService: myService
    });
  }));

  it('should call myService service and populate the array', function(){
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.list1.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });

});
```

This works great, I have a passing test as I would expect.  But when I try and test the following examples I keep getting errors.

```
expect(scope.list2.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
Expected undefined to be greater than 0.

expect(list1Available).toEqual(false);
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: list1Available
```

Like I said these are my first tests so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try $rootScope.$digest(); //to resolve/reject the promise

```
 it('should call myService service and populate the array', function(){
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(scope.list1.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
```

You need to attach list1Available && scope.list2Available to $scope so they can be accessed outside of the controller.

```
function getMyLists() {
  getLists.getOne().then(function(listOne) {
    $scope.list1 = listOne[0];
    $scope.list1Available = true;
  });
  getLists.getTwo().then(function(listTwo) {
    $scope.list2 = listTwo;
    $scope.list2Available = true;
  });
}
```

your test needs to test for scope.list1Available

```
expect(scope.list1Available).toEqual(false);
```